# Disable babel strict mode from webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

So far I haven't found any **COMPLETE** example on this.  There are answers talking about `babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode`, but no code about how it should be configured.

Can anybody provide a simple working code snippet for how to configure the babel loader to disable strict mode?  Thanks

Comment: This is babel 6, so black list doesn't work anymore

Comment: How about using [this preset](https://github.com/fancyboynet/babel-preset-es2015-without-strict)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll add a simple config below.

Also note that if you use ES6 syntax (like import instead of require), webpack will automatically add "use strict" as all ES6 modules are expected to be strict mode code.

```
var config = {
    entry: {
        home: buildBundle( 'home' ),
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        "presets": [
                            ['es2015', {modules: false}]
                        ],
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ]
    },
};
```